# Reimplementing Jasig CAS HTTPModule in ActionFilters

Tags: cas, httpmodule, jasig

At the moment I am trying to implement the Jasig CAS HttpModule in Orchard CMS.

The CMS is setup using multi-tenancy which means any changes to the web.config file should be minimal and not client specific.

The problem is that the default module provided for CAS is a HTTPModule which will override any kind of Authentication within Orchard CMS for all clients.

Do you see any issues with reimplementing the CAS HTTP Module using MVC Action Filters?

Has anyone attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

So there were not many pain points in implementing this so here it is... https://github.com/Jetski5822/NGM.CasClient